# Can $((x+a) ^n \bmod (x^r-1)) \bmod n $ be reduced to $ a^n \bmod n + x^{n \bmod r}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

For the sake of manually implementing the [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#cite_note-AKS-1) I've tried to simplify the following expression:

$$((x+a) ^n \bmod (x^r-1)) \bmod n $$

I have tested some values of $n$ and was always able to reduce this to
$$a^n \bmod n + x^{n \bmod r}$$

It seems to work for all $ n < 15000 $ and for a few thousand $ n > 10 ^{10} $.

Is it possible to prove the formula $$((x+a) ^n \bmod (x^r-1)) \bmod n = a^n \bmod n + x^{n \bmod r}$$ for all $ n > 1 $ under the conditions $ n \neq p^q (p, q \in \mathbb{N})$, $a \le r \lt n$, $gcd(a, n) = 1$, $gcd(r, n) = 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
n=10, \quad r=7, \quad a=1
$$
so $a\le r < n $ and $n\neq p^q$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1 < n$ and $\gcd(a,n)=1, \gcd(a,r)=1$ as required.

Then the two expressions are

$$ 
\big((x+1)^{10}\bmod (x^7-1)\big)\bmod 10
$$
and
$$
1^{10} (\bmod 10)+ x^{10\bmod 7}
$$

Let now $x=2$ then
$$
\big(\underbrace{(2+1)^{10}\bmod (2^7-1)\big)}_{121}\bmod 10=1
$$
and
$$
\underbrace{1^{10} (\bmod 10)}_{1}+ \underbrace{2^{10\bmod 7}}_{2^3=8}=9
$$

So I think that the assumption is not true.

Comment: Yes, seems like I have forgotten another condition of the AKS test in my question. I have updated it

Comment: @lncr And I edited my answer

Comment: I don't even know anymore o.O I won't edit my answer for a 2nd time though. Thanks for quickly disproving it.